# Why I lose the variable value when doing form.ShowDialog()?

Tags: c#, winforms

See this:
MAIN FORM CODE:

```
public partial class Principal : Form
{
    string directoriodelarchivo;
    ... 


    ....
    private void opendicomdir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        directoriodelarchivo = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName);
        var form = new dicomdirselectionform(_reader);
        form.ShowDialog();  
    }
}
```

I do some stuff in the other form and then press a button to return to the main form, thing is that when I returin to the main form, the variable "directoriodelarchivo" IS EMPTY!

Why that is? I'm new to C# and I'm trying to figure out if there's something I'm missing

Comment: What is the value of `directoriodelarchivo` before you show the dialog? Is something in your selection form setting it? What do you *expect* the value to be?

Comment: all of said above plus do you create an openfiledialog at class level or in a separate method and try to get it(the instance variable) in the click handler?

Comment: Thanks for the reply:
Basically: directoriodelarchivo is declared as string in the Class and no value is set until the user clicks to open the files.
opendicomdir_Click is part of the Principal Class. That } is wrong there.
openfiledialog is at class level

Comment: So what do u do in `dicomdirselectionform`? If I were you (since ur new to C#) I would put a break point on the assignment statement then add `directoriodelarchivo` to ur watch window then step into your code step-by-step to find which line is changing its value. You need to keep in mind the scope of the variable and where you are in the debugging process

Comment: Thanks! How can I add directoriodelarchivo to the watch window?

Comment: Ok, so I've done that, and I think where the problem is...
I open a new form, then on that 2nd form, I call a method of the 1st form by doing this:<br>var form = new Principal(); and then all variables are set to their defaults again..

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 causes for that

1. You re-create this form somehow. So it has value by default.
2. You change that var in some code. Just try to find references for that var and you will make sure it.

I hope it will help you!

Comment: So, here's what happen:
When I press the button to return to the previous form, it goes to the right top where all variables are declared (including directoriodelarchivo) and sets it as null...
How can I prevent that?
The Click in the 2nd form is like this:
<code>var form = new Principal();</code>
<code>form.clickboton(botonpresionado, _readern.Dicomdir);</code>

Comment: So I think what happens is that I re create the form then all variables are set to their default values again.. How can I prevent that?

Comment: @Matimont Just check where you have `var myForm  = new YourForm();` Make sure you do it once otherwise you have to check the logic that probably calls it multiple times.

Comment: I have a main form, the from that one, a user clicks and gores to a second one, from that second one, the user does some stuff then clicks on a button that executes a function in the main form. For some reason, when I do  var form = new MainForm(), it goes to the class and steps through the variable declaration.. I want to avoid that so that the variable is intact

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear to me what may be causing this. To try to find the reason, I would suggest doing something like this:

1. Remove all other code that may be altering `directoriodelarchivo`.
2. Add some easy way to check the value of `directoriodelarchivo` after every step in your code. (Example: https://ideone.com/E38zc2)
3. If this works, try finding the code that you removed in step 1 that's breaking your application by changing `directoriodelarchivo`. If it doesn't, `ofd.FileName` might be causing an unsatisfactory value for `directoriodelarchivo`.